# Python regex, matching absolute beginning of string, nothing else before

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
(\b)(con)
```

This matches:

```
.con
con
```

But I only want to match the second line 'con' not '.con'.

This then needs expanding to enable me to match alternative words (CON|COM1|LPT1) etc. And in those scenarios, I need to match the dot afterwards and potentially file extensions too. I have regex for these. I am attempting to understand one part of the expression at a time.

How can I tighten what I've got to give me the specific match I require?

Comment: you need to add `^` prefix to your regexp

Comment: Maybe you should look at, os.path.splitext.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:**

You can use non-delimited capture groups and [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) (which is anchored to the start of the string):

```
>>> from re import match
>>> strs = ["CON.txt", "LPT1.png", "COM1.html", "CON.jpg"]
>>> # This can be customized to what you want
>>> # Right now, it is matching .jpg and .png files with the proper beginning
>>> [x for x in strs if match("(?:CON|COM1|LPT1)\.(?:jpg|png)$", x)]
['LPT1.png', 'CON.jpg']
>>>
```

Below is a breakdown of the Regex pattern:

```
(?:CON|COM1|LPT1)  # CON, COM1, or LPT1
\.                 # A period
(?:jpg|png)        # jpg or png
$                  # The end of the string
```

You may also want to add `(?i)` to the start of the pattern in order to have case-insensitive matching.

Comment: I understand how this works but it doesn't answer my specific requirements. I have expanded my question to improve the context I gave initially. Let me know if you still think this adequately answers my question.

Comment: @RossSpencer - No.  For your new requirements, I'd use Regex.  See my edit.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks. The reason I asked for regex in the first place! :) I appreciate the revisit of your answer.

Comment: @RossSpencer - Happy to have helped! If you are all set, then I ask that you please don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).  Otherwise, I'd be glad to help further.

Comment: +1, and for an obnoxious optimization: `(?:CO(?:M1|N)|LPT1))\.(?:jp|pn)g$` :)

Answer (score 3):

`^` matches start of a string:

```
^con
```

would work.

Comment: How do I expand this to increase the word list, say CON|ABC|DCE ?